# Question about proper morphism and support of sheaf.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $\pi : Z\to S$ be a proper morphism of noetherian schemes. Let $Y\subset Z$ be a closed subscheme, and $\mathcal{F}$ be a coherent sheaf on $Z$. Then it’s said that there exists an open subscheme $S’\subset S$ with the universal property that a morphism $T\to S$ factors through $S’$ if and only if the support of the pull back of $\mathcal{F}_T$ on $Z_T=Z\times _S T$ is disjoint from $Y_T=Y\times T$.

I was quite confused at the first place. So I tried to understand it under affine case. Suppose $S= \operatorname{Spec} R,Z=\operatorname{Spec} A,T=\operatorname{Spec} B$, and $Y=\operatorname{Spec}(A/a)$, where $a$ is and ideal of $A$. The coherent sheaf $\mathcal{F}$ is $\widetilde{M}$ for some $A-$ module $M$. Then the support of $\mathcal{F}_T$ can be seen as support of $B\otimes _SA$-module $B\otimes _SA_A\otimes M$, i.e. $V(b)=V(\operatorname{Ann}(B\otimes _SA\otimes _A\otimes M))$ where $\operatorname{Ann}$ denotes the annihilator. And $Y_T=\operatorname{Spec}(A/a\otimes B)=V(a\otimes B)$. Now, since the support is disjoint from $Y_T$, we have $V(b)\cap V(a\otimes B)= V(b+a\otimes B)= \varnothing$, which means $b+a\otimes B= A\otimes B$.

On the other hand, suppose $T\to S$ factors through $U=\operatorname{Spec}(R_f)\subset S$, then the corresponding homomorphism of rings factors as $R\to R_f\to B$. In other words, all prime ideals of $R$ containing $f$ are in the kernel of the homomorphism.

I got stuck showing these two conditions are related to each other. Hope someone could help. Thanks!

Comment: A formatting tip: \operatorname{Ann} will format $\operatorname{Ann}$ and \operatorname{Spec} will format $\operatorname{Spec}$ with the correct spacing.

Comment: Thanks for the formatting tip.